# Software for adjusting the velocity curve of a MIDI controller

Tags: ubuntu, midi

I use my yamaha clp330 digital piano as a midi controller. The problem is that the volume of the sound is too low when I play on the piano. But using software controllers the sound is normal. So it seems that the velocity value on my digital piano is set too low. I use Ubuntu Studio on my computer. Is there any software for linux for adjusting the velocity curve in realtime?

Comment: Just to double check, could you record midi from the external hardware into a program and check if the extremities (v. loud and v. soft) are what you expect?

Comment: Perhaps have a look at http://www.midish.org/

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to save a song to a flash drive to check that. But Unfortunatly my piano is not so user friendly.

Comment: @Sparhawk I checked that. I recorded a MIDI file from my piano to a flash drive, then I played it in my computer, using the same synthesizer. Still the same problem exist with the recorded midi file. The sound is low compared to software midi controlers and also other midi files I have downloaded.

Comment: Okay, it looks like it's probably the piano itself then. There is no evidence to suggest that the MIDI input into your computer is to blame. I'm not sure how to do it in real time, but hopefully you get a good answer here from someone else.

Comment: @Sajjad: I am having the exact same problem. Did you ever solve it? If you did, would you consider writing the solution as an answer to your own question, so that I and others can see it?